# Unable to import rmgarch model in Colab Python environment

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, time-series, google-colaboratory

I want to use rmgarch for Multivariate time series analysis, as Python doesn't have Multivariate model, I'm trying to use R's rmgarch package.

Im trying to import rmgarch model in Colab Python environment using below code.

Below is the error it returns, did anyone face any such issue?

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
package_name = "rmgarch"

try:
    pkg = importr(package_name)
except:
    ro.r(f'install.packages("{package_name}")')
    pkg = importr(package_name,lib_loc='/usr/local/lib/R/site-library')
pkg
```

Error:

```
R[write to console]: Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘rmgarch’
Calls: <Anonymous> ... loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart -> doWithOneRestart
R[write to console]: Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
R[write to console]: also installing the dependencies ‘gmp’, ‘Rmpfr’, ‘Bessel’
R[write to console]: The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpI6uWBQ/downloaded_packages’
R[write to console]: Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘rmgarch’
Calls: <Anonymous> ... loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart -> doWithOneRestart
R[write to console]: In addition: 
R[write to console]: Warning messages:
R[write to console]: In install.packages("rmgarch") :
R[write to console]:  installation of package ‘gmp’ had non-zero exit status
R[write to console]: 2: 
R[write to console]: In install.packages("rmgarch") :
R[write to console]:  installation of package ‘Rmpfr’ had non-zero exit status
R[write to console]: In install.packages("rmgarch") :
R[write to console]:  installation of package ‘Bessel’ had non-zero exit status
R[write to console]: In install.packages("rmgarch") :
R[write to console]:  installation of package ‘rmgarch’ had non-zero exit status
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RRuntimeError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-e4fba63eb683> in <module>()
      7 try:
----> 8     pkg = importr(package_name)
      9 except:
6 frames
RRuntimeError: Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘rmgarch’
Calls: <Anonymous> ... loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart -> doWithOneRestart
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
RRuntimeError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rpy2/rinterface.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    787                     error_occured))
    788             if error_occured[0]:
--> 789                 raise embedded.RRuntimeError(_rinterface._geterrmessage())
    790         return res
    791 

RRuntimeError: Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘rmgarch’
Calls: <Anonymous> ... loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart -> doWithOneRestart
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue, for me the cause was that Colab was unable to install the **gmp** R package, which is required for several R packages.

The workaround is that you have to install the **gmp** library manually:

1. If you're in an R kernel, then `system("sudo apt-get install libgmp-dev")`
2. If you're in a Python kernel (as you are), then I think `!apt-get -qq install -y libgmp-dev`

After that the R package import for the packages that use gmp should be fine.

Comment: `system("sudo apt-get install libgmp-dev")` did the trick for me. Thanks!